# Why is my Google Chrome Extension not working in Google Chrome Version 41.0.2272.89

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, plugins, google-chrome-extension

I just upgraded Google Chrome on two computers to Version 41.0.2272.89, and the Google Chrome Extension I developed and have had on the Google Web Store for the past year no longer works.

Here is my manifest file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Maurice Wright - Note and Bookmarking App",
  "description": "Don't forget a thing! Easily save your most important notes and bookmarks. Use Mobile Safari's \"Add to Home Screen\" for iPads.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "ico_logo.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "icons" : {
    "48" : "ico_logo_48.png",
    "128" : "ico_logo_128.png"
  }
}
```

Here is my popup.html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
    <style>
      body {
        min-width: 357px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
      }

      img {
        margin: 5px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 75px;
        height: 75px;
      }
    </style>

    <!--
      - JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files: see our Content Security
      - Policy documentation[1] for details and explanation.
      -
      - [1]: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html
     -->
    <body></body>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

And, here is my popup.js file:

```
var bookmarker = function() {

  var init = function() {
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        myFunction(tab.url,tab.title);
    });
  }

  var myFunction = function(tablink,tabtitle) {
    url = 'http://mwright.com/popup?title='+encodeURIComponent(tabtitle)+'&link='+encodeURIComponent(tablink);
    popup(url);
  }

  var popup = function(url) {
    var width  = 600;
    var height = 300;
    var left   = (screen.width  - width)/2;
    var top    = (screen.height - height)/2;
    var params = 'width='+width+', height='+height;
    params += ', top='+top+', left='+left;
    params += ', directories=no';
    params += ', location=no';
    params += ', menubar=no';
    params += ', resizable=no';
    params += ', scrollbars=no';
    params += ', status=no';
    params += ', toolbar=no';
    newwin = window.open(url,'windowname5', params);
    if ( window.focus ) { newwin.focus() }
    return false;
  }

  return {
    init :      init
  }

}();

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  bookmarker.init();
});
window.close();
```

This has worked for the past year. I'm not sure what changed, how to find out what changed, or how to make the necessary change to get the extension back up-and-running.

I've tried "Inspect Popup" in developer mode, but don't see any errors in the console.  I should mention that on the mac using OSX 10.9.2, the "Inspect Popup" button opens a popup window and closes it immediately. On the mac using OSX 10.7.5, the popup stays open, and no errors are apparent.

These files were tested when loaded locally in developer mode.

EDIT:
Paul provided the solution that was used to solve this problem below, and is the accepted answer. Apparently the latest release of Google Chrome treats window.close() differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just guessing, because you didn't specify what the desired outcome should be. Does it open a window that says "Maurice Wright's Note and Bookmarking App", and has a login form?

I believe you're not seeing the window because at the bottom of popup.js you have `window.close()`. So your window opens and closes before you can realize what's happening. The same goes for inspect popup. That's because chrome extensions run in their own scope. It's the same as inspecting a tab, and closing that tab. Your inspector will also close.

If you take out window.close(), I think it will work how you wish. By the way, I'm working on a Windows 7 machine with Chrome 43.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I knocked this out a few hours ago, and updated the extension. Removing the window.close() was the problem in the latest version of Google Chrome. I'm not sure why Chrome treats it different now, but at least the problem is solved.

Comment: Your bug was always there. the latest chrome exposed it. not sure why before chrome wasnt closing it.